# here-api returns different traveling times in the same request

Tags: javascript, api, here-api

I am calculating a route with the here.com Direction API. The problem: The API returns different traveling times in the same request. Or I just don't understand the response.

The summary object return this **travelTime: 8944 = 2:19h** 
The same summary objects returns a travelTime of **2:13h within the text attribute**.

What's wrong here?

**The summary objects**

```
summary: {distance: 164517, trafficTime: 8944, baseTime: 7998, flags: ["motorway", "builtUpArea"],…}
_type: "RouteSummaryType"
baseTime: 7998
distance: 164517
flags: ["motorway", "builtUpArea"]
text: "The trip takes <span class="length">165 km</span> and <span class="time">2:13 h</span>."
trafficTime: 8944
travelTime: 8944
```

**The JSON Request:**

http://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=eBl7de5PjwgKbnDwNnCW&app_code=81OJhBoVtT5mrLvn7mJisg&mode=fastest%3Bcar%3Btraffic%3Aenabled&waypoint0=geo!52.428010%2C10.786407&waypoint1=geo!passThrough!52.982994%2C10.566552&waypoint2=geo!53.546913%2C10.004310

Comment: What's the difference between baseTime, trafficTime and travelTime. I could find an answer in the API reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find the description of different times here :
https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/routing/topics/resource-type-route-summary.html

TrafficTime : Contains the travel time estimate in seconds for this element, considering traffic and transport mode. Based on the TrafficSpeed. The service may also account for additional time penalties, so this may be greater than the element length divided by the TrafficSpeed.

BaseTime : Contains the travel time estimate in seconds for this element, considering transport mode but not traffic conditions. Based on the BaseSpeed. The service may also account for additional time penalties, therefore this may be greater than the element length divided by the BaseSpeed.

TravelTime : Total travel time in seconds optionally considering traffic depending on the request parameters.

Comment: Thanks. I'll choose TravelTime with mode:traffic:enabled